# How to do Junit for Spring classes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

How can I perform Junit Testing on Spring classes without any Database dependency.

for example, if I want to write junit test case for a service class, Automatically dependent Dao, then data sources are being instantiated as those classes are @autowired.

**Is there any way to use some other component during testing which will work as a in-memory/temporary database during junit ?**

Comment: Google "mocking frameworks", I personally  use [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) for Java but there are other alternatives out there. Your use case would probably involve mocking your DAO and making them return whatever test  data you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to use embedded database as the datasource:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>

</jdbc:embedded-database>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
     <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Doc link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support